# How can I get real cursor or update it or reset it?

Tags: python, mysql, sockets

I have three py files:Client,Server and SQL

As my design,everytime when run Client,Server should call SQL to add data to MySQL,or print 'It has been added'.

But when I get 'It has been added',then delete data in MySQL,SQL do not add data again,still show 'It has been added'.

As my design,everytime get data from Client,Server should call SQL.

When I delete data in MySQL,common_ID should be False,but it is still the last number.

**SQL**

```
def main(computer_name,user_name):
     print '==========SQL start=========='
     common_ID=searchComputerName(computer_name)
     if(common_ID):
         print'01'
         if(compareUserName(common_ID,user_name)):
             print"It has been added."
         else:
             updateUserName(common_ID,user_name)
     else:
         common_ID=searchUserName(user_name)
         if(common_ID):
             updateComputerName(common_ID,computer_name)
         else:
             addNewItem(user_name,computer_name)
     print '===========SQL end==========='

def searchComputerName(computer_name):
     print'->searchComputerName'
     c = db.cursor()
     sql="SELECT * FROM `mtk_pc_name` WHERE name='%s'"%computer_name
     print sql
     a=c.execute(sql)
     print a
     if(c.execute(sql)):
         common_ID = c.fetchone()[0]
         print common_ID
         c.close()
         return common_ID
     else:
         print'searchComputerName false'
         c.close()
         return False
```

**Server**

```
def clientThread(conn):
    print'->clientThread'
    message = conn.recv(1024)
    data = message.split(' ')
    computer_name = data[0]
    user_name = data[1]
    main(computer_name,user_name)
    reply = 'OK'
    conn.sendall(reply)
    print "reply OK"
    conn.close()
    print 'clone.close'
while 1:
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    print'Connected with'+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1])
    clientThread(conn)
    print 'End\n'
```

Comment: How do you delete data from mysql?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I use phpMyAdmin, so just click delete on the page

Comment: Is that auto commit? if not, did you commit after that?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I am not sure so I type  in SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1 to set it. But still can not add data.

Comment: @AnandSKumar input SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%autocommit%', and get variable_name: autocommit value:ON. I am sure it is auto commit

Comment: just to be sure, try using mysql console to delete and then do `commit;` as well

Comment: @AnandSKumar You are right! After I use SQL to delete data,it can be added again! So the problem is changes in phpMyAdmin is not real changes in mysql. It is a big problem.

Comment: What is the exact thing you are using? A screenshot or so would be nice

Comment: @AnandSKumar Sorry I can not post screenshot because I am using remote desktop and my computer is net forbidden. I just setup the pypMyAdmin and it provides MySQL service.

Comment: @AnandSKumar sorry I make a mistake.It still can not add data.I forget to get 'It has been added'state first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.

In each function in SQL add the following:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=hostName,user=userName,passwd=password,db=database)

cursor=db.cursor()
```

It`s working OK now.

Obviously I will extract it as parameter of function. At last ,it looks like this:

```
def searchComputerName(computer_name,cursor):
def addNewItem(user_name,computer_name,cursor,db):
```

Although I do not konw why global db and cursor declared at first do not work well.